# Probability of an equal number of factors of a successor

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\Omega(n)$ be the total number of prime factors of $n$ (e.g $\Omega(12)=\Omega(2*2*3)=3$).

Consider these probabilities (probably they have a name):

- $P_{>}(n)$ the probability that $\Omega(n+1) > \Omega(n)$
- $P_{<}(n)$ the probability that $\Omega(n+1) < \Omega(n)$
- $P_{=}(n)$ the probability that $\Omega(n+1) = \Omega(n)$

And the same probabilities, with an increment of 2; e.g.:

- $P'_{=}(n)$ the probability that $\Omega(n+2) = \Omega(n)$

What are the values of these limits (if known):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P_{=}(n)$ i.e. the probability that a successor of a number $n$ have the same number of factors of $n$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P'_{=}(2n)$ i.e. the the probability that the even successor of an even number $n$ have the same number of factors of $n$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P'_{=}(2n-1)$ i.e. the the probability that the odd successor of an odd number $n$ have the same number of factors of $n$

Are they all zero?

Comment: $F$ is usually denoted $\Omega$ -- see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function). The limits you ask about are probably all $0$.

Comment: @mathworker21: thanks replaced $\Omega$ instead of $F$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely speaking, $\Omega(n)$ is approximately normal with mean and variance $\log\log n$. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) We expect $\Omega(n)$ and $\Omega(n+1)$ to behave like independent random variables. So we expect that all your probabilities containing an equal sign have a limit of zero, while the probabilities containing $>$ or $<$ are expected to approach $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks I ran a small numeric test and the behavior of $P'(2n)$ vs $P'(2n-1)$ was not so clear, so I asked.

Comment: Because $\log \log n$ grows so slowly, it's difficult to verify any of this empirically.